# how to fetch document library data in SharePoint Framework, Modern UI

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-framework, typescript, modern-pages

to build a simple web-part to display document library using SharePoint Frame Work, that using type script how to get connected to SharePoint Document Libraries?

Answer (score 2):

there is already `"Add-ins"` WebPart to display documents in the modern Pages

[image]

Just Choose `Highlighted content` WebPart, Configure it as you want

[image]

```
not smart to develop an app when it's already exist ;)
```

Answer (score 1):

You use Microsofts own PnP Core JavaScript library:

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core